# Spliter Using Angular UI

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

We using angularjs in our web page.we need a splitter for that page.Is there a way to setup a splitter in an Angular-UI webpage? We don't want to link to any plugin that references jQuery-UI.

Comment: http://blackgate.github.io/bg-splitter/

Comment: what is a `splitter`? Seems like a term that can be interpreted different ways making it unclear what you are asking for

Comment: something like frames in html i think